# What is this series? $\cos\frac{\pi z^2}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^n \pi^{2n +1} z^{4n +3} }{1 \cdot 3 \cdots\left(4n + 3\right)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, soft-question

Before I began to study mathematics, a friend of mine bought me a shirt with the imprint of a formula. I did not know what these characters were and had no desire to think about it. Yesterday, I cleaned out my closet and found this shirt (After three years study of mathematics). I looked at this formula again and realized that this formula has been a series, i.e.

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} z^2\right)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-1\right)^n \pi^{2n +1} z^{4n +3} }{1 \cdot 3 \cdots\left(4n + 3\right)} = ?$$

I don't know if $z$ should be a complex or a real number. Also I can't figure out if this series converge or not.

**My question:**

> Is this a known series? Does this series converge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have asked it without mentioning the shirt. At first I thought you want to buy a t-shirt with a mathematical formula, and I was like this is not ebay... I was so gonna close it, and downvote. :P

Comment: A formula without a story? ;)

Comment: Looks like it converges everywhere.

Comment: It's absolutely convergent by the ratio test

Comment: Is this the best title to the question, I wonder.

Comment: The summand can be written as $$ (-1)^n (2\pi)^{2n+1} z^{4n+3} (2n+1)! / (4n+3)! $$ which can presumably be simplified further and written in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: I think there is an error, and that "n" starts at 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $~(4n+3)!!~=~\dfrac{(4n+3)!}{(4n+2)!!}~=~\dfrac{(4n+3)!}{(2n+1)!}\cdot\dfrac1{2^{2n+1}}~$ and $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2n+1)!}{(4n+3)!}~(2x)^{4n+3}=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2\cdot$

$\cdot\Big(e^{x^2}~\text{erf }x-e^{-x^2}~\text{erfi }x\Big),~$ it follows from [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) that our infinite series, were it to

begin at $n=0$, would equal $~C(z)~\sin\bigg(\dfrac\pi2~z^2\bigg)-S(z)~\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2~z^2\bigg),~$ where *C* and *S* are the

two [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is $\prod_{k=0}^n(4k+3) > 4^n n!$, so (for instance) by comparison with the series for the exponential, this power series has infinite radius of convergence.

It converges  for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. The function defined by this series itself, however, is not known -- to me.

Comment: The denominator starts with $1\cdot 3\cdot...$ which suggests that the product should be $\prod_{k=0}^{2k-1}(2n+1)$. Not that it makes much difference.